# The best way to sort list by item name length

Tags: java, performance, list, java-8

Which of this ways is the best, looking at speed and comfort?

```
names.sort( (a,b) -> a.getName().length() - b.getName().length() );


Collections.sort(names, Comparator.comparing( s -> Celebrity.getName().length() ))


BiFunction<Celebrity,Celebrity,Integer> bifunc = (a,b) -> Integer.compare(a.getName().length(), b.getName().length());
Collections.sort( names, bifunc::apply );
```

Comment: Please add the language tag.

Comment: Why don't you meassure your approaches?

Comment: Start with correctness (a broken solution isn't worth much). Then optimize for readability. Once you've nailed those two and can demonstrate that performance of this particular part of the system is an overall bottleneck, profile and optimize for performance (also google "Amdahl’s law").

Comment: @Flown cause then I should have a large dataset to get correct result. it is only tidbit for me.

Comment: Well, we cannot tell you what is better since we have to meassure these snipptets too. Since SO isn't a free coding service you have to verify on your own using a benchmark harness (e.g. JMH).

Comment: well.. that's why I ask about this here. Maybe someone did this before, or know smth and wants to share their knowledge.

Comment: Using `Comparator.comparingInt( s -> s.getName().length() )`, note `comparingInt` instead of `comparing` avoids code duplication *and* boxing. While avoiding code duplication has no performance impact, it improves the code quality and helps avoiding errors, which is much more important. While a JIT may elide the overhead of the unnecessary `BiFunction` detour and boxing in the 3rd example, it’s still better not to have it in the first place, especially as it is also convoluted source code-wise and additionally contains the code duplication of the first variant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the same. look at `Collections.sort` method :

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
   list.sort(c);
}
```

All 3 approaches are sorted by the same algorithm.

You should write code as much as readable as possible. Don't do premature micro-optimalizations unless really needed.

I would use this one line:

`names.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(celebrity -> celebrity.getName().length()));`